# How to convert 2d Collection into 1d in java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, collections

Is there any way to convert `2d Collection` into `1d`?

the output is : `[[hello, hallo], [hi]]`

requiered is : `[hello,hallo,hi]`

**my Try:**

```
Collection<Collection<String>> st = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<String> co1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<String> co2 = new ArrayList<>();
    co1.add("hello");
    co1.add("hallo");
    co2.add("hi");
    st.add(co1);
    st.add(co2);
    System.out.println(st);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `Java8+` you can use something like:

```java
Collection<String> result = st.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But note that I do not treat duplicates separately here.

Comment: Just replace `Collectors.toList()` to `Collectors.toSet()` and this will remove all duplicates.